# Joining multiple collections in different databases with $lookup

Tags: mongodb-query, lookup

I am a beginner to Mongo. I want to simulate an inner join using the aggregate $lookup and I have 3 collections ( 1 in a separate database ) I want to see all the projects that a user is part of can someone give me an example?

Here are the 3 collections

"projects.details"

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5684f3c454b1fd6926c324fd"),
        "projName" : "I am a test project",
        "active" : "true"
        "projId" : "project1"
    }
```

"userDetails.projMembership"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
    "projId" : "project1",
    "userId" : "user1",
    "status" : "Invite"
}
```

"userDetails.details"

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56d82612b63f1c31cf906003"),
    "userId" : "user1",
    "email" : "user1@somemail.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching far and wide for an answer, The answer is simple **This is NOT possible in Mongo.** The only way to achieve the result I was looking for is to perform a `$lookup` for the 2 collections in the `userDetails DB`, store the results in an array, then perform another lookup against the collection in the `projects DB`. Hope this helps someone out there.